# AOJ の問題：x !=== 0 のとき、１つの整数 x を読み込み、それをそのまま出力するプログラム

Tags: javascript

#### 実現したいこと

１つの整数 x を読み込み、それをそのまま出力するプログラムを作成

https://onlinejudge.u-aizu.ac.jp/courses/lesson/2/ITP1/3/ITP1_3_B

##### input

- 入力は複数のデータセットから構成されています。各データセットは１つの整数 x を含む１行から構成されている
- x が 0 のとき入力の終わりを示し、このデータセットに対する出力を行ってはいけない

##### output

各データセットごとに、以下の形式で x を出力して下さい

```
Case i: x
```

i = num
x = key

#### 作成したソースコード

```js
"use strict";

const input = require("fs")
    .readFileSync("/dev/stdin", "utf8")
    .split(" ")
    .map(Number);     //"input"を取得し配列に変換

for (const key of input) { 
    let i = 1;        //index番号
    if (key !== 0) {  //keyが0ではないとき
        console.log(`Case ${i}: ${key}`);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: 自身が作成したコードではどのような問題があるのかを説明してください。(AOJ の出題かどうかはあまり重要ではありません)

Comment: それがわからないのです。AOJのエンジンに入力して見るのですが、AOJはwrongとだけ表示してどこが間違っているのかわかりませんでした。そこで、ブラウザで試してみるのですが、これはうまくいくのです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 入力例を見ると入力の区切り文字は改行のようです。
2. for文の中でiを初期化してはいけません。

2点修正すると下記のようになるでしょう。

```
"use strict";

const input = require("fs")
    .readFileSync("/dev/stdin", "utf8")
    .split("\n")
    .map(Number);     //"input"を取得し配列に変換

let i = 1;        //index番号
for (const key of input) { 
    if (key !== 0) {  //keyが0ではないとき
        console.log(`Case ${i}: ${key}`);
        i++;
    }
}
```